# Pass variables from shell script to groovy

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I need to read a file with contents in groovy
file
string1
string2
string3
Expected output is string1,string2,string3
I cannot use file io commands as I cannot use java.io for security reasons
I tried sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/ file', I need to return the output of this shell command to groovy.
I tried the below command
def contentList = sh(returnStdout: true, script:"sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' file")
but it is giving the error
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
The command works fine in unix without the escape characters.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

def contentList = sh(returnStdout: true, script:"sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' file")

just had to add additional escape characters to \n